# UItextview cursor position

Tags: swift, uitextview

I've a UITextview with these constraints:
Align Center x,y  and width and height equals.

When I click the `UItextview` for the first time the cursor is like:

[image: 1]

### When I write inside:

[image]

### When I delete characters:

[image]

what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UITextView` height is too small and it's contentSize height is bigger than it's frame height. A `UITextView` is a subclass of an `UIScrollView` so it's content is scrolling, this is what's happening in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause by  textContainerInset.

you can add the follow code to solve:

```
tetxView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

other strange issue maybe you can solve by this:

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```